# MySQL select query

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL wildcard in select …](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582144/mysql-wildcard-in-select)

> **SELECT icon_* FROM `images` WHERE 1**

I have three fields, `icon_small`, `icon_big`, and `icon_large`. How do I get all three without manually specifying them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't. You will have to manually specify them.

(See the duplicate)

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify them in your `SELECT`, but you can select a list of columns (which can then only be used in [dynamic SQL](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/introduction-to-dynamic-sql-part-1)) by doing:

```
select column_name from information_schema.columns 
                   where table_schema = database()
                         and table_name = 'mytesttable' 
                         and column_name like 'icon_%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set @qry = (select concat('select ',group_concat(column_name), ' from ' ,table_name) from
information_schema.columns
where table_schema = database()
and table_name = 'your_table_name'
and column_name like 'icon_%');

prepare stmt from @qry;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```