# Wildcards in column name for MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I am trying to select multiple columns, but not all of the columns, from the database. All of the columns I want to select are going to start with "word".

So in pseudocode I'd like to do this:

```
SELECT "word%" from searchterms where onstate = 1;
```

More or less. I am not finding any documentation on how to do this - is it possible in MySQL? Basically, I am trying to store a list of words in a single row, with an identifier, and I want to associate all of the words with that identifier when I pull the records. All of the words are going to be joined as a string and passed to another function in an array/dictionary with their identifier.

I am trying to make as FEW database calls as possible to keep speedy code.

**Ok, here's another question for you guys:**

There are going to be a variable number of columns with the name "word" in them. Would it be faster to do a separate database call for each row, with a generated Python query per row, or would it be faster to simply SELECT *, and only use the columns I needed? Is it possible to say SELECT * NOT XYZ?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use rows rather than columns?

Comment: Well, the problem with that, and it may be my database design (it has been such a headache on this project), is that then I'd need a row for EACH word, and an associated value, and I don't want that as these words are all related. They will be part of the same query to the API. Others, with a different identifier will be a different query.

Comment: If you have a new question, use a new post. Answerers are not notified of you editing this post, let alone that you edited it to ask another question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, SQL doesn't provide you with any syntax to do such a select.

What you *can* do is ask MySQL for [a list of column names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html) first, then generate the SQL query from that information.

```
SELECT column_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'your_table'
    AND column_name LIKE 'word%'
```

let's you select the column names. Then you can do, in Python:

```
"SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE " + ' '.join(['%s = 1' % name for name in columns])
```

Instead of using string concatenation, I would recommend using [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) instead to do the SQL generating for you.

However, if all you are doing is limit the number of columns there is no need to do a dynamic query like this at all. The hard work for the database is selecting the rows; it makes little difference to send you 5 columns out of 10, or all 10.

In that case just use a `"SELECT * FROM ..."` and use Python to pick out the columns from the result set.

Comment: Wouldn't this, in practical terms, give me the exact list I had to use?

Comment: Yes, but you'll have to use Python to then construct the final SQL; there is no pure SQL way of implementing your psuedocode query.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot dynamically produce the list of columns to be selected. It will have to be hardcoded in your final query.

Your current query would produce a result set with one column and the value of that column would be the string `"word%"` in all rows that satisfy the condition.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the list of column names first by using

```
SHOW COLUMNS IN tblname LIKE "word%"
```

Then loop through the cursor and generate SQL statement uses all the columns from the query above.

```
"SELECT {0} FROM searchterms WHERE onstate = 1".format(', '.join(columns))
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be helpful: [MySQL wildcard in select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582144/mysql-wildcard-in-select)

In conclusion it is not possible in MySQL directly.

What you could do as a dirty workaround is get all the column names from the table with an initial query (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html) and then compare in python if the name matches your pattern. Afterwards you could do the MySQL select statement with the found column names like this:

```
SELECT word1, word2, word3 from searchterms where onstate = 1;
```