# Can I use star notation in MySQL after a word, like med*

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with columns with the same name and a number after it, like:
med1, med2, med3,  med4..... etc.

Is it posible to do something like this:

```
Select medewerker.med*
FROM table
```

Instead of this?:

```
Select medewerker.med1, 
       medewerker.med2,  
       medewerker.med3, 
       medewerker.med4
FROM table
```

Comment: Did it work? No. I'm guessing no then! ;-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wildcards in column name for MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11466764/wildcards-in-column-name-for-mysql)

Comment: Having multiple columns with the same name and type and with enumerated names is usually a sign of a poor database design.  Typically, you want to replace the columns with a junction table.

Comment: However, this points to a more serious problem with your data model - i.e. a lack of normalization.

Comment: In short, no you can't. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11466764/wildcards-in-column-name-for-mysql) question.

Comment: The question is, is there any way so it DOES work?

Answer (score 0):

Nope. you can use LIKE in a where clause but definitely not when specifying the columns to select

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead if the only fields are the ones specified above.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
```

if not you cannot use a LIKE statement on column SELECT's.

if you are refering to values inside the `medewerker` column then use

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE medewerker LIKE 'med%'
```